# SSH/SOCKS/HTTP Proxy

Tags: networking, ssh, server, headless

I use [Google Chrome Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable) regularly on a computer where I have no administrator rights or access to network settings. I want to use my Raspberry Pi as a proxy from my house so I can use my internet connection when I'm not at home. The Chrome extension [Proxy Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-helper/mnloefcpaepkpmhaoipjkpikbnkmbnic) allows HTTP, HTTPS and SOCKS proxys (proxys? proxies?).

I think I also read somewhere that it's possible to start SSH as a SOCKS server?

- What are the differences?
- Which one is easiest to implement?
- Which ports do I have to forward?

Many thanks

Comment: what is your client OS? (Mac OS X, Linux, Windows, etc.?)

Comment: Windows but i can't change any of the network settings on windows,i have to change them on the chrome extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSH tunnels for that.

- To work with SSH tunnel, you need permission to connect ssh port (default 22) outside of your office network. You can ask this to your network administrator.
- To create ssh tunnel to your RPi, your RPi should set up as ssh server and you need forward ssh port from your home router to your pi.

If your network setup OK for those options, you can set up your SSH Tunnel with putty. (free ssh client)

You can find a good information at link below about creating ssh tunnel to your home network.

http://howto.ccs.neu.edu/howto/windows/ssh-port-tunneling-with-putty/

Then, setup your Chrome extension, put your Rpi's public IP address and port that you forwarded as SOCKS proxy. You should able to connect through your home network with this setup.

Comment: The example given uses `localhost` and acts as if I typed `localhost` on the pi. If i use any other website, will it retrieve it using the pi's internet connection?

Comment: @LukeMoll because 'localhost' is given, just you can connect through SSH tunnel.